# 'Trying to get property 'value_type1' of non-object' in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I have the following query running in a function:
`$sensor = Sensor::where('id', $measurement->sensor_id)->with('sensorType', 'sensorType.valueType1', 'sensorType.valueType2')->first();`

This returns the following response:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "DHT22 Kantoor",
    "sensor_type_id": 1,
    "active": 1,
    "organisation_id": 1,
    "disabled_until": null,
    "created_at": null,
    "updated_at": "2020-07-15T11:12:33.000000Z",
    "sensor_type": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "DHT22",
      "value_1_type_id": 1,
      "value_2_type_id": 2,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "value_type1": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Temperatuur",
        "unit": "°C",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      },
      "value_type2": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Luchtdruk",
        "unit": "Pa",
        "created_at": null,
        "updated_at": null
      }
    }
```

I am trying to get the 'Temperatuur' that is in this response in the following way:

`$affValue = $sensor->sensor_type->value_type->name;`

But this gives me the following error:
`Trying to get property 'value_type1' of non-object`

I've tried doing the following:
`$sensor->name` returns `DHT22 Kantoor`
`$sensor->sensor_type->id` gives the same error as before

Am I trying to access this value wrong? Or is there a diffrent solution?

Comment: Try `dd($sensor->sensor_type);` and what do you get?

Comment: @aynber this returns `null`

Comment: @aynber I figured  it out, writing an answer right now

Answer (score 0):

I got it working now.
Instead of using `sensor_type` i needed to use `sensorType`
The same for `value_type1`, it needed to be `valueType1`
So instead of using the name that's in the response you need to use the name that is in the `App\SensorType`.